# Angular 6 validation on submit

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular-reactive-forms

I have a situation where I need to validate fields only after submit.

Since I have a very big form with FormArrays and FormGroup in these I split up the form into multiple components so that each component represents on group.
Moreover, I have a general component which is used to provide easy creation of Input + validation messages.

However, Angular does validate form as soon as you type and has no default option to start validation after submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution #1

First and very easy to use is to have some property on parent component e.g. `submitted = false` which becomes `true`(manually) when the user submits the form. Then pass it deep down until it reaches my general input component via lots of `@Input()`s. Then I had to use it and use it in `ngIf` as an extra condition to show errors.

---

### Solution #2

I came to it after meditating over Material Angular inputs and theirs custom validation matchers. I went to the source and found that there in base class `NgForm` and `FormGroupDirective` are being passed in constructor. A while after I realized that it's a dependency injection (in Angular there is a possibility to navigate up tree with help of [dependency injection](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-navtree#unable-to-find-a-parent-by-its-base-class)) thus I came up to solution that on could use DI to get the FormGroupDirective/NgForm which have `submitted` property. Thus, we can have `submitted` property **only** in general input component. And update it like

```
constructor(
  @Optional() private form: NgForm,
  @Optional() private group: FormGroupDirective,
) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.group.ngSubmit.subscribe(e => {
    this.submittd = this.group.submitted || this.form.submitted;
  });
}
```

I've created a small example to see that you can see how the property can be tracked.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oreyhv)

First, open the console and see the initial FormGroupDirective state.

Button `Funny button` only prints in console current state of NgForm and FormGroupDirective.

Second, press the submit button. The ngSubmit event is triggered and is successfully tracked. Then press the `Funny button` and see the updated `submitted` status (on FormGroupDirective).

And one more example, but with error message + input color indicator. 
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9kkgr7) it's enough to delete value, then click "Submit" to check it.

Answer (score -1):

As you can see in [this](https://netbasal.com/boosting-performance-with-the-new-updateon-option-in-angular-v5-18857279ace2) article, you can do the following:

```
this.login = new FormGroup({
   email: new FormControl(),
   password: new FormControl()
}, { updateOn: 'submit' });
```

Comment: It's update. Not validate and then annoy the user until they do it properly